# My.pyw file only executes when I open and save it using Visual Studio Code or run it using cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

Am I missing something? Isn't it meant to operate independently?
Once the machine is turned on and I log in, I want the code to execute in the background. I have an output Excel file that continuously saves the updates from this Python code.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please add the code. Also how have you planned to run it once user logs in? You can do this by adding the program to task scheduler or startup (windows). There is no way to answer your question without these bits of information.

Comment: After I added the .pyw file to the Windows Startup folder, it started functioning. This is acceptable, right? Is there anything I need to watch out for?